# Constraining names with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have this state properties:

```
export interface IStateProps
{
    location: LocationState;

    userId: number;
    counter: number;

    companyComponent: ICompanyComponent;
}
```

I want the reducers to conform to the names above:

```
const reducers: {[name in keyof IStateProps]} = {
    location        : locationReducer,
    counter         : counterReducer,
    userId          : userIdReducer,
    companyComponent: companyComponentReducer
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);

const middlewares = applyMiddleware(middleware);
const composed    = compose(enhancer, middlewares);
const store       = createStore(rootReducer, composed);

// While redux is in version 3.7.2,
// overwrite redux/index.d.ts with this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/redux/index.d.ts
// const s = store.getState();
// so autocomplete or object destructuring would work
```

However, that results to getState() missing the counter property:

[image]

Are there any ways the object's properties names can be constrained from an  interface's property names while maintaining the object's type? And checked during compile-time.

---

An unrelated question to above, where to find the settings for aligning properties' types of an interface declaration using WebStorm? And what's the corresponding TsLint for it?

Comment: from looking at redux typings, it looks like you have to pass the state type explicitly to combineReducers. Like `const rootReducer = combineReducers<IStateProps>(reducers);`

Comment: @dbandstra If i declare reducers without the `name in keyof IStateProps`, that is, just this: `const reducers = {`; even without the IStateProps generic parameter passed to `combineReducers(reducers)`, the counter property is showing in getState()'s autocomplete, no compile-time error. combineReducers' typing is smart enough to iterate the properties even without the `<IStateProps>` passed.

Anyway, for the meantime, I'll go with your solution, pass the `<IStateProps>` to combineReducer's generic parameter,  counter is now showing in getState()'s autocomplete.